# Disable Hiera debug logging

Tags: ruby, hiera

I'm using Hiera (the ruby library, not the command line tool, or puppet integration) to retrieve data from an existing set of Hiera YAMLs (which we do use for puppet), for use in Capistrano. I'm able to get this working as intended... but I cannot seem to get rid of the debug output that seems to be the default:

```
$ sudo cap deploy
WARN: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Not using Hiera::Puppet_logger. It does not report itself to be suitable.
WARN: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Cannot load backend puppet: cannot load such file -- hiera/backend/puppet_backend
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking up package_repo_base in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking for data source environments/PROD/LDN
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking for data source regions/LDN
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Cannot find datafile /etc/customer/hieradata/regions/LDN.yaml, skipping
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking for data source environments/PROD
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Found package_repo_base in common
WARN: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Not using Hiera::Puppet_logger. It does not report itself to be suitable.
WARN: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Cannot load backend puppet: cannot load such file -- hiera/backend/puppet_backend
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking up puppet_deploy_base in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking for data source environments/PROD/LDN
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking for data source regions/LDN
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Cannot find datafile /etc/customer/hieradata/regions/LDN.yaml, skipping
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking for data source environments/PROD
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2014-10-29 12:17:09 +0000: Found puppet_deploy_base in common

**************************************************************************************************************************************************
* Recording output in: deploy.20141029-121709+0000.log *
**************************************************************************************************************************************************

  * 2014-10-29 12:17:09 executing `deploy'
  * 2014-10-29 12:17:09 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
```

At the moment this is just an annoyance more than anything, but the extended output (I've trimmed the output above) makes the logging fairly noisy, and I'd love to be able to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to sort this out by setting the config hash in the hiera call within the deploy.rb:

```
def hiera_lookup(key,default=nil,order_override=nil,resolution_type=:priority)
    hiera_yaml = File.realpath('./puppet/hiera.yaml')
    config = YAML.load_file(hiera_yaml)
    config[:logger] = 'noop'

    scope = YAML.load_file("/etc/hiera/hiera.conf")
    hiera = Hiera.new(:config => config)

    hiera.lookup("#{key}", default, scope, order_override, resolution_type)
end
```

Setting the `config[:logger]` key to 'noop' suppressed the output from hiera completely.

Comment: I looked at this recently, if you change :logger in hiera.yaml to noop, that will do the same, without having to change the source.

Comment: Yes indeed - however, for my use case, I need to maintain the existing :logger as it is, and amend the output at runtime (this is used in Capistrano). The code example listed is not the source, it's a helper method in my deploy.rb

Comment: Ah, that's what I was looking for too.  Good to know.